Source for Test if Two Populations have Different Defect Rates
I have two populations of items and I want to test if the defect rate between them is statistically difference. I have a sample from both populations of different sizes and I know the number of defective items in each sample. I found this site which gives an unnamed test that does exactly what I want:

If the samples are reasonably large we can use the normal approximation to the binomial to develop a test similar to testing whether two normal means are equal.
Let sample 1 have $x_1$ defects out of $n_1$ and sample 2 have $x_2$ defects out of $n_2$. Calculate the proportion of defects for each sample and the $z$ statistic below:
$z = \frac{\hat{p}_1 - \hat{p}_2}{\sqrt{ \hat{p}(1-\hat{p})(1/n_1 + 1/n_2) }} \, ,$
where
$\hat{p} = \frac{n_1 \hat{p}_1 + n_2 \hat{p}_2}{n_1 + n_2} = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{n_1 + n_2} \, .$
Compare $|z|$ to the normal $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ table value for a two-sided test.

I want to know more about this test (specifically how large samples need to be for it to be accurate), but I cannot find any other sources for this formula. Does anyone know another source about this test, or even just a name so I can look into it better?

I've been taught to call this as just the "test of two proportions", though "z test for two proportions" is probably more common. There are no absolute rules of sample size, but "at least 10 cases in each cell" is often mentioned.

What you are trying to do is estimating 2x2 contingency tables. You may want to look at this post in CV, for some answers. This article also looks at several methods for doing this. And this web site, lets you do so online (only a few methods).
There are many methods to do this comparison of proportions in 2 populations; Fisher, Fisher-Irwin, Fisher exact, etc. (all different names for the same thing), or $\chi^2$, Pearson-$\chi^2$ (same thing) are the 2 major ones, but each then can have a multitude of variants (mid-P, pooled and unpooled variances, with or w/o continuity correction, using N-1, Agresti-Coull, etc...). So many flavors. The specific one you found is the basic $\chi^2$ with pooled variances (aka Pearson).Note that with some many factors to choose from, there are on-going debates as to which one is "best" (for given situations).
Note also that the "traditional" suggestion to use $\chi^2$ for "large" sample sizes is a relic from the past: Fisher-exact (and its variants, including more recently Blaker) requires one to use combinatorics, i.e. factorials. Doing so with pen and paper (back in the days before computers) for large sample sizes (beyond 20?) was indeed untractable. You could spend days, and easily make a mistake. But with today's computers, this takes a few seconds at most.
$\chi^2$ and its variants are all normal approximations of the binomial; and they are also continuous approximations of discrete distributions. As such, these approximations have drawbacks (the discussion of which is left for another time/place). So, w/o any additional context than what you provided (you used an Engineering web site as your source), generally, you are better off using Fisher (or one of its variants; e.g. mid-P, or Blaker) than a normal approximation. This is particularly true when your proportion of "success" is very high (or proportion of "failures" is very low) where the corresponding binomial distribution does not at all look normal. Such scenarios are extermely common in engineering applications (where you expect your product to be virtually defect-free). So, in your case, I would suggest you look at the Fisher-exact and related tests. But yes, there are valid arguments to be made in favor of one of the many flavors of 2x2 contingency tests (based Fisher of $\chi^2$) beyond these 2 basic ones, depending on the context, but that would be for another answer...
